# Command not found when executing through lxc-attach

Tags: debian, lxc

I am running Arch Linux with a Debian *lxc* container.

The container is running and I am able to login via `lxc-console -n name`.

If I use `lxc-attach -n name` and try to execute a command like `ls` or something other basic things I get `bash: ls: command not found`.

Any hints where I have to set a `PATH` variable?

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` show?  If the problem is that Arch only includes /usr/bin, this might be relevant: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194624

Comment: It seems to include the host path `/opt/sencha/cmd:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`. Where do I have to adjust this? using lxc-attach --clear-env helped but I do not want to add this every time